# akka stream consume web socket

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, reactive-streams

Getting started with akka-streams I want to build a simple example.
In chrome using a web socket plugin I simply can connect to a stream like this one https://blockchain.info/api/api_websocket via `wss://ws.blockchain.info/inv` and sending 2 commands

- `{"op":"ping"}`
- `{"op":"unconfirmed_sub"}`
  will stream the results in chromes web socket plugin window.

I tried to implement the same functionality in akka streams but am facing some problems:

- 2 commands are executed, but I actually do not get the streaming output
- the same command is executed twice (the ping command)

When following the tutorial of http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.7/scala/http/client-side/websocket-support.html or http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.0/scala/http/client-side/websocket-support.html#half-closed-client-websockets
Here is my adaption below:

```
object SingleWebSocketRequest extends App {

implicit val system = ActorSystem()
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

import system.dispatcher

// print each incoming strict text message
val printSink: Sink[Message, Future[Done]] =
    Sink.foreach {
      case message: TextMessage.Strict =>
        println(message.text)
    }

      val commandMessages = Seq(TextMessage("{\"op\":\"ping\"}"), TextMessage("{\"op\":\"unconfirmed_sub\"}"))
      val helloSource: Source[Message, NotUsed] = Source(commandMessages.to[scala.collection.immutable.Seq])

      // the Future[Done] is the materialized value of Sink.foreach
      // and it is completed when the stream completes
      val flow: Flow[Message, Message, Future[Done]] =
      Flow.fromSinkAndSourceMat(printSink, helloSource)(Keep.left)

      // upgradeResponse is a Future[WebSocketUpgradeResponse] that
      // completes or fails when the connection succeeds or fails
      // and closed is a Future[Done] representing the stream completion from above
      val (upgradeResponse, closed) =
      Http().singleWebSocketRequest(WebSocketRequest("wss://ws.blockchain.info/inv"), flow)

      val connected = upgradeResponse.map { upgrade =>
        // just like a regular http request we can access response status which is available via upgrade.response.status
        // status code 101 (Switching Protocols) indicates that server support WebSockets
        if (upgrade.response.status == StatusCodes.SwitchingProtocols) {
          Done
        } else {
          throw new RuntimeException(s"Connection failed: ${upgrade.response.status}")
        }
      }

      // in a real application you would not side effect here
      // and handle errors more carefully
      connected.onComplete(println) // TODO why do I not get the same output as in chrome?
      closed.foreach(_ => println("closed"))
    }
```

when using the flow version from http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.0/scala/http/client-side/websocket-support.html#websocketclientflow modified as outlined below, again, the result is twice the same output:

```
{"op":"pong"}
{"op":"pong"}
```

See the code:

```
object WebSocketClientFlow extends App {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  import system.dispatcher

  // Future[Done] is the materialized value of Sink.foreach,
  // emitted when the stream completes
  val incoming: Sink[Message, Future[Done]] =
    Sink.foreach[Message] {
      case message: TextMessage.Strict =>
        println(message.text)
    }

  // send this as a message over the WebSocket
  val commandMessages = Seq(TextMessage("{\"op\":\"ping\"}"), TextMessage("{\"op\":\"unconfirmed_sub\"}"))
  val outgoing: Source[Message, NotUsed] = Source(commandMessages.to[scala.collection.immutable.Seq])
  //  val outgoing = Source.single(TextMessage("hello world!"))

  // flow to use (note: not re-usable!)
  val webSocketFlow = Http().webSocketClientFlow(WebSocketRequest("wss://ws.blockchain.info/inv"))

  // the materialized value is a tuple with
  // upgradeResponse is a Future[WebSocketUpgradeResponse] that
  // completes or fails when the connection succeeds or fails
  // and closed is a Future[Done] with the stream completion from the incoming sink
  val (upgradeResponse, closed) =
    outgoing
      .viaMat(webSocketFlow)(Keep.right) // keep the materialized Future[WebSocketUpgradeResponse]
      .toMat(incoming)(Keep.both) // also keep the Future[Done]
      .run()

  // just like a regular http request we can access response status which is available via upgrade.response.status
  // status code 101 (Switching Protocols) indicates that server support WebSockets
  val connected = upgradeResponse.flatMap { upgrade =>
    if (upgrade.response.status == StatusCodes.SwitchingProtocols) {
      Future.successful(Done)
    } else {
      throw new RuntimeException(s"Connection failed: ${upgrade.response.status}")
    }
  }

  // in a real application you would not side effect here
  connected.onComplete(println)
  closed.foreach(_ => {
    println("closed")
    system.terminate
  })
}
```

How can I achieve the same result as in chrome

- display print of subscribed stream
- at best periodically send update (ping statements) as outlined in https://blockchain.info/api/api via `{"op":"ping"}`messages

Note, I am using akka in version `2.4.17` and akka-http in version `10.0.5`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A couple of things I notice are:

**1)** you need to consume all types of incoming messages, not only the `TextMessage.Strict` kind. The blockchain stream is definitely a Streamed message, as it contains loads of text and it will be delivered in chunks over the network. A more complete incoming Sink could be:

```
  val incoming: Sink[Message, Future[Done]] =
    Flow[Message].mapAsync(4) {
      case message: TextMessage.Strict =>
        println(message.text)
        Future.successful(Done)
      case message: TextMessage.Streamed =>
        message.textStream.runForeach(println)
      case message: BinaryMessage =>
        message.dataStream.runWith(Sink.ignore)
    }.toMat(Sink.last)(Keep.right)
```

**2)** your source of 2 elements might complete too early, i.e. before the websocket responses come back. You can concatenate a `Source.maybe` by doing

```
val outgoing: Source[Strict, Promise[Option[Nothing]]] =
    Source(commandMessages.to[scala.collection.immutable.Seq]).concatMat(Source.maybe)(Keep.right)
```

and then

```
  val ((completionPromise, upgradeResponse), closed) =
    outgoing
      .viaMat(webSocketFlow)(Keep.both)
      .toMat(incoming)(Keep.both)
      .run()
```

by keeping the materialized promise non-complete, you keep the source open and avoid the flow shutdown.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this great introduction. Could you explain why you used `.viaMat(webSocketFlow)(Keep.both)` and why `.concatMat(Source.maybe)(Keep.right)` requires the `Keep.right` as these two are not yet clear to me.

Comment: the `Keep` functions are used to decide which of your stages' materialized values you want to keep around. `Source.maybe` materializes to a `Promise` you can complete to emit a value from the source. In this example I am not doing anything with it, but you might want to complete that Promise at some point to make the stream complete (otherwise it will stay alive forever). More on materialized values here (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.0/scala/stream/stream-flows-and-basics.html#Combining_materialized_values)

Comment: Is http://blog.akka.io/integrations/2016/08/25/simple-sink-source-with-graphstage the right place to look when I would want to modularize the flow into reusable graph stages?