# akka stream custom graph stage

Tags: akka, akka-stream, reactive-streams

I have an akka stream from a web-socket like [akka stream consume web socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43598434/akka-stream-consume-web-socket) and would like to build a reusable graph stage (`inlet`: the stream, `FlowShape`: add an additional field to the JSON specifying origin i.e.

```
{
...,
"origin":"blockchain.info"
}
```

and an `outlet` to kafka.

I face the following 3 problems:

- unable to wrap my head around creating a custom `Inlet` from the web socket flow
- unable to integrate kafka directly into the stream (see the code below)
- not sure if the transformer to add the additional field would be required to deserialize the json to add the *origin*

The sample Project (flow only) looks like:

```
import system.dispatcher
implicit val system = ActorSystem()
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

val incoming: Sink[Message, Future[Done]] =
    Flow[Message].mapAsync(4) {
      case message: TextMessage.Strict =>
        println(message.text)
        Future.successful(Done)
      case message: TextMessage.Streamed =>
        message.textStream.runForeach(println)
      case message: BinaryMessage =>
        message.dataStream.runWith(Sink.ignore)
    }.toMat(Sink.last)(Keep.right)

val producerSettings = ProducerSettings(system, new ByteArraySerializer, new StringSerializer)
    .withBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")

val outgoing = Source.single(TextMessage("{\"op\":\"unconfirmed_sub\"}")).concatMat(Source.maybe)(Keep.right)

val webSocketFlow = Http().webSocketClientFlow(WebSocketRequest("wss://ws.blockchain.info/inv"))

val ((completionPromise, upgradeResponse), closed) =
    outgoing
      .viaMat(webSocketFlow)(Keep.both)
      .toMat(incoming)(Keep.both)
      // TODO not working integrating kafka here
      // .map(_.toString)
      //    .map { elem =>
      //      println(s"PlainSinkProducer produce: ${elem}")
      //      new ProducerRecord[Array[Byte], String]("topic1", elem)
      //    }
      //    .runWith(Producer.plainSink(producerSettings))
      .run()

val connected = upgradeResponse.flatMap { upgrade =>
    if (upgrade.response.status == StatusCodes.SwitchingProtocols) {
      Future.successful(Done)
    } else {
      throw new RuntimeException(s"Connection failed: ${upgrade.response.status}")
      system.terminate
    }
  }

// kafka that works / writes dummy data
val done1 = Source(1 to 100)
    .map(_.toString)
    .map { elem =>
      println(s"PlainSinkProducer produce: ${elem}")
      new ProducerRecord[Array[Byte], String]("topic1", elem)
    }
    .runWith(Producer.plainSink(producerSettings))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue is around the `incoming` stage, which is modelled as a `Sink`. where it should be modelled as a `Flow`. to subsequently feed messages into Kafka.

Because incoming text messages can be `Streamed`. you can use `flatMapMerge` combinator as follows to avoid the need to store entire (potentially big) messages in memory:

```
  val incoming: Flow[Message, String, NotUsed] = Flow[Message].mapAsync(4) {
    case msg: BinaryMessage =>
      msg.dataStream.runWith(Sink.ignore)
      Future.successful(None)
    case TextMessage.Streamed(src) =>
      src.runFold("")(_ + _).map { msg => Some(msg) }
  }.collect {
    case Some(msg) => msg
  }
```

At this point you got something that produces strings, and can be connected to Kafka:

```
  val addOrigin: Flow[String, String, NotUsed] = ???

  val ((completionPromise, upgradeResponse), closed) =
    outgoing
      .viaMat(webSocketFlow)(Keep.both)
      .via(incoming)
      .via(addOrigin)
      .map { elem =>
        println(s"PlainSinkProducer produce: ${elem}")
        new ProducerRecord[Array[Byte], String]("topic1", elem)
      }
      .toMat(Producer.plainSink(producerSettings))(Keep.both)
      .run()
```

Comment: This works great as a starter! But how can I 1) create a transformer which adds `"origin":"blockchain.info"` a field and 2) create a graph stage from it? (here a runnable sample code https://github.com/geoHeil/akkaStreamsIngest)

Comment: 1) just add a flow after `incoming` that adds whatever you want to the message (see amended code)
2) what do you want to create a graph stage from?